# How to push a string into a vector of shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, shared-ptr

If I have a vector of shared pointers (V1) and a vector which contains a lot of strings (V2) . How to use the shared_ptr inside of the V1 to points to the elements inside of V2?

EX:

```
std::vector< std::shared_ptr< SImplementation > > V1;  
std::vector < std::string > V2; // there are strings in the V2 already

for(auto i : V2){
    V1.push_back(i) // I tried this way, but it does not work because of the different types, different types mean int, string, unsigned long
}
```

Can I use a iterator something or use another shared_pointer to point to the strings in V2?

Comment: What is `type` in this example?

Comment: Pointers, smart or not, are not containers. What are you really trying to do? What is the problem you want to solve? Are you perhaps wanting a vector of pointers to the elements in `V2`? Why? Again, what is the problem (real and original problem) you need to solve?

Comment: vector of shared pointers to *what*?

Comment: V1 is not even a vector

Comment: @HuangMolly: please provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Right now you keep people guessing what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

`std::shared_ptr` is a tool to manage the ownership of memory. The problem here is that `std::vector` already manages its memory. Also, `std::vector` invalidates references and pointer to its elements when resizing or erasing an element.

What you probably want is to have two vector of a shared resource. That resource would be shared between the two vectors:

```
// there are strings in the V2 already
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> V1;  
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> V2;

for (auto ptr : V2) {
    V1.push_back(ptr) // now works, ptr is a std::shared_ptr<std::string>
}
```

What if you cannot change the type of `V2`? Then you'll have to refer to the object in a different way, such as indices to the vector and keeping them synched when erasing elements.

Comment: Because the V1 is a different type which is .                                   
         std::vector< std::shared_ptr< SImplementation > >                so I can't do push_back directly.

Comment: Ah! Then it changes everything. But I have no clues what you're tring to do then... Why do you want a `std::shared_ptr<SImplementation>` to point to a `std::string`? Do you want to create new `SImplementation` that has the string value or something like that or you actually want one type to refer to an object of another type?

Comment: I want the shared_ptr inside of the V1 to point to the strings in V2, but they are different type. So it really confuses me.

Comment: @HuangMolly well, it can't. You can't for the same reason why `int* int_ptr = new std::string` won't compile. It does not make sense sadly.

Answer (score 1):

`std::shared_ptr` does not have a member function `push_back`. It can point to at most one object (or an array since C++17).

> How to push a string into a vector of shared_ptr?

Like this:

```
std::string some_string;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> ptrs;
ptrs.push_back(std::make_shared<std::string>(some_string));
```

Comment: I forgot to do the vector type for the V1.